# copying and pasting from one workbook and then using find function

Tags: excel, vba

While copying and pasting worksheet from one workbook to another cells.find method giving

> run time error 91.

The code is being written in another workbook.

```
Sub OpenWorkbook()    
    Dim ws As Worksheet      
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsm")
    Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\HP\Desktop\ind_niftysmallcap100list.xlsx")
    Workbooks("ind_niftysmallcap100list.xlsx").Activate
    Worksheets("ind_niftysmallcap100list").Activate

    ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=Workbooks("New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsm").Sheets(1)
    Workbooks("ind_niftysmallcap100list.xlsx").Close
    Workbooks("New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsm").Activate

    ActiveSheet.Name = "Overview"
    Workbooks("New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsm").Activate

    ws.Cells.Find(What:="CARE Ratings Ltd.", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
End Sub
```

I expect that find function works properly.

Comment: Worksheets("ind_niftysmallcap100list").Activate . can you try `.select` and then try running your find function

Comment: The code is still giving runtime error 91 in cells.Find(What:="CARE Ratings Ltd.", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Comment: I can say that the issue in the above code is you're not using the `find` statement properly. It needs to be used with a `range` method. But, please also add what you would like the code to actually do. That will give an idea on how to proceed.

Comment: So I want to copy the worksheet from one workbook to another and then rename the worksheet to "overview". And the last step would be to find cell value with ""CARE Ratings Ltd.". The above code has been written in a fresh workbook and not the the one that I am using i.e. "ind_niftysmallcap100list.xlsx" and New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsm.

Comment: Well I believe range worked for me. Thank you so much!. But I really want to know the difference between range.find vs cells.find as I am beginner in Excel VBA.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find) you always need to test if it found something.

```
Dim FoundCell As Range

Set FoundCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="CARE Ratings Ltd.", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then 'check if something was found
    FoundCell.Select
Else
    MsgBox "'CARE Ratings Ltd.' was not found."
End If
```